# Help With Derivations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I am currently studying Quantum Field Theory and am using the textbook *Overview of Quantum Field Theory* by Peskin and Schroeder. Equation (2.31) derives the total Hamiltonian of the Klein Gordon field, but skips a lot of study. In order to get some practice with the mathematics I am trying to derive the equation. Here is what I have done using the formulae provided in chapter 2. $\pi$ is the canonical momentum density and $\phi$ is the canonical "position" quantum field.

$$H = \int d^3x \bigg(\frac{\pi^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2 + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi \bigg).$$

Using equation 2.28 for the momentum density, we see

$\frac{\pi^2}{2} = \frac{-1}{(2\pi)^6} \int d^3 p d^3p'\frac{\omega_{p}}{4} (a_p - a_{-p}^{+})e^{ip\cdot x}(a_{p'} - a_{-p'}^{+})e^{ip' \cdot x}\\ 
= \frac{-1}{(2\pi)^6} \int d^3 p d^3p'\frac{\omega_{p}}{4} (a_p - a_{-p}^{+})(a_{p'} - a_{-p'}^{+})e^{i(p' \cdot x + p\cdot x)}\\
=\frac{-1}{(2\pi)^6} \int d^3 p d^3p'\frac{\omega_{p}}{4} (a_p a_{p'}- a_p a_{-p'}^{+} - a_{-p}^+ a_{p'} + a_{-p}^{+}a_{-p'}^{+}) e^{i(p' \cdot x + p\cdot x)}\\$

Using equation 2.27 for the $\phi$ quantum field we see

$\nabla \phi = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3 p}{\sqrt{2\omega_{p}}}ip e^{i p\cdot x}$

Thus $\frac{(\nabla \phi)^2}{2} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{1}{4} \int d^3p d^3p'\frac{-p \cdot p'}{\sqrt{\omega_{p'} \omega_{p}}}(a_p + a_{-p}^{+})(a_{p'} + a_{-p'}^{+})e^{i(p\cdot x + p' \cdot x)}\\$

We also see that
$\frac{m^2 \phi^2}{2} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{1}{4} \int d^3p d^3p'\frac{m^2}{\sqrt{\omega_{p'} \omega_{p}}}(a_p + a_{-p}^{+})(a_{p'} + a_{-p'}^{+})e^{i(p\cdot x + p' \cdot x)}\\$

(Here $\phi^2 = \phi(x,p)\phi(x,p')$; similar for $\pi^2$). The textbook says that the total Hamiltonian is given by

$H = \int d^3x \int \frac{d^3 p d^3p'}{(2\pi)^6} e^{i(p + p')\cdot x}\bigg[-\frac{\sqrt{\omega_p \omega_{p'}}}{4}(a_p - a_{-p}^+)(a_{p'} - a_{-p}^{+}) + \frac{-p \cdot p - m^2}{4\sqrt{\omega_p \omega_{p'}}}(a_p + a_{-p}^+)(a_{p'} + a_{-p}^{+}) \bigg]$

which makes sense from the previous derivations I made. However, the textbook also says that the the total Hamiltonian is also equal to

$\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\omega_p \bigg(a_p^+ a_p + \frac{1}{2}[a_p, a_{p'}^+].  \bigg)$

and I am having trouble understanding why this is true. Can anyone explain why this last equality holds?

Comment: You need to integrate over x to obtain the delta-function, then use it to perform integration over p' and  simplify the expression with operators.

Comment: @AleksandrArtemev Thank you !!!!

Comment: Was struggling with this problem, but really all you need to do is expand the commutator and you will see the result to agree with your earlier expression.